# What is the smallest n that fits the requirements?

Tags: factoring

What is the smallest value of $n$ if $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) \equiv 0 \pmod{2000}$

Comment: Does $n=0$ count? What about $n=-3$?

Comment: I suppose what I was trying to ask is this: *Are we restricting ourselves to the positive integers?*

Comment: Assuming you meant $n>0$, Hint:  at most one of those terms can be divisible by $5$ hence that term must be divisible by $5^3$.

Comment: I'm sorry for not adding, **n** is a natural number. And thanks for the hint, i figured it out.

Comment: Also at most one term will be divisible by four.  Another by 2 but not 4.  2000 =125 x 16 so the term divisible by 4 must be divisible by 8.  So you need the smallest multiple of 125 that is 3 with a multiple of 8.

Comment: If you have figured it out, John, let me encourage you to post an answer. Then, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Observe here that $5$ will divide atmost one term out of $n,n+1,n+2,n+3$ because these are four consecutive natural numbers (assuming $n>0$). Therefore $125$ will be the factor of one these term. Also $2$ will always divide two term in these  and $4$ will divide atmost one term , this means we need not to care about factor $8$ but we want little more $i.e$ some term which is divisible by $8$ not just $4$.
Now hoping one term to be $125$ we look upon product of four possible consecutive numbers out of $122,123,124,125,126,127,128$ we found that $128\equiv0($ mod $16)$. Therefore we take $125,126,127,128$. Consequently , $$125\times126\times127\times128\equiv0(mod \quad2000)$$ And hence smallest $n$ is $125$.